# How do i display these formated text without HTML tags

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, ckeditor4.x

I am using CKeditor 4 to format text and store it in a database with Node.js and MySQL. The data type i used to store this is `TEXT`. Everything is fine until it is stored in the database.
The problem is when i retrieve the text from the database and try to display it using an EJS variable as follows:

```
<%=result.FormatedText%>
```

the browser displays the content in the EJS variable like this:

```
<p><strong>This is a random text i typed</strong></p> <ol> <li>First item</li> <li>Second item</li> <li>third item</li> </ol> <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

but I want to display it like this:

> **This is a random text i typed**
>
> 1. First item
> 2. Second item
> 3. third item

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
<%= result.FormatedText %>
```

To this:

```
<%- result.FormatedText %>
```

It outputs the unescaped value, the browser could now render it.

Check the [documentation](https://ejs.co/#docs).